# How do you add an avatar profile to django inbuilt forms?

Tags: python, django

How can you add a field to add images on a inbuilt Django form? Here is the code of my form.py:

```
class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-user', 'type':'password', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'Password'}),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label="Confirm password",
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-user', 'type':'password', 'align':'center', 'placeholder':'Confirm Password'}),
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        widgets = {
            'username': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Username'}),
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
        }

        fields = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

Comment: Are you trying to accept an image as a field or render an image in the form?

Comment: accept an image and then render it, I know how to render it but I don't know how to accept a image

Comment: Have you reviewed the [ImageField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#imagefield)?.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the build-in django `User` model.
Django User model doesn't have an avatar field. So what you should do is extend your default User model by creating a One-to-one relationship to another model with the avatar field

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to = "avatars/", null=True, blank=True)
```

then use the django `post_save` signal to automatically create the `UserProfile` modal instance when a `User` instance is created.

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from yourapp.models import UserProfile

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

after that you'll be able to access the avatar field with the Modal Forms